# Why are the HTML ids generated by Orbeon and the Proxy Portlet sometimes inconsistent between deploys?

Tags: orbeon

One of my forms has a drop-down control named: `now_.applicationInformation.firstAid_.attendantCertificateLevel`

It is a `<xf:select1>`.

The form is displayed in Liferay using the Proxy Portlet. In the generated HTML, the `<select>` element usually has this id:

`o0now_.applicationInformation.applicationInformation_-control≡now_.applicationInformation.mineInformation_.proposedActivities_-control≡xf-685≡now_.applicationInformation.firstAid_.attendantCertificateLevel-control≡select1≡≡c`

We have some automated tests that rely on the id being the same. Yesterday the script failed because the id was:

`o0now_.applicationInformation.applicationInformation_-control=now_.applicationInformation.mineInformation_.proposedActivities_-control=xf-685=now_.applicationInformation.firstAid_.attendantCertificateLevel-control==c`

The two ids are mostly the same except that the first ends with `control≡select1≡≡c` and the second ends with `control≡≡c`.

The issue seemed to resolve itself the next day without any intervention. So now the first id is generated as before.

Any idea why this inconsistency is occurring?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the separator, I cannot see why this would be happening. The separator has been `≡` for a long time now, and there was never an `=` separator in use. I could imagine an encoding issue, but it would still be puzzling.

Comment: I notice that when I paste the `≡` into the TextPad editor it converts it to `=`. It looks like that's what happened. I'll edit my question. Do you have any idea about the missing `select1≡≡`?

Comment: `control≡select1≡≡c` appears to indicate a `select1` control nested within an XBL control, while `control≡≡c` appears to indicate a plain control without XBL. Is the original an `fr:dropdown-select1` by any chance? It almost sounds like in one case the XBL binding was not applied.

Comment: Both environments are using the same form definition. I verified by pulling it from the two databases and doing a diff. I thought that it was a redeploy of Orbeon that fixed this, but it turns out that I had accidentally done the redeploy in a different environment. This means that the issue resolved itself without me doing anything at all. Very peculiar.

Comment: A completely wild guess, but this would be compatible with issue [#3327](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3327), which we still haven't resolved.

Comment: For information, we have now fixed at least one case where this could happen. The fix will be available in Orbeon Forms 2017.2.3 and Orbeon Forms 2018.1.